# How to define geometry from intersecting planes?

Tags: geometry, knife-tool

Is there a way to create a 3d shape by using intersecting planes? The image shows 6 planes that define an enclosed cuboid. I tried joining the planes, then using the knife tool with self-intersection, but the result did not generate vertices where three planes intersect. I know I could do it in steps by first joining the 4 vertical planes and using the knife tool, then join that to the horizontal planes and repeating, but that becomes tedious for more complex shapes.

This was done in 2.79, but I'm open to suggestions for 3.0 as well.
[image: wonky cuboid]

Comment: This comment is probably frustrating.. but _Knife (Intersect)_ with 'Self-Intersect' checked, and set to 'Cut' works for me in 3.0 . Maybe  some tweaks necessary, where edges exactly coincide?

Comment: That's actually good to hear! I'll be using 3.0 tomorrow, so if it turns out to be just a version difference, I'll let you know so you can add a reply for me to accept, thanks!

Comment: I actually ended up just extruding the faces outwards, then used a boolean modifier (union) to define the verts and edges, then deleted the unwanted faces and welded the rest together. It's not a great solution though, so I'm not adding it as an answer.